# c# - Error executing child request for handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, controller

When i re-publish my project to my host, and try to display my view i get this error about 50% of the times depending on how lucky i am

> Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

my view gets called by

```
@if (Model.Items.Any())
{
    var item = Model.Items.FirstOrDefault();
    var table = item.GetValue("table");

    // Render Action (controllerMethod, ControllerName, UmbracoModelData)
    Html.RenderAction(table, "Monitor", new {data = item});

}
```

and this is my method in the controller that should return my view

```
    public ActionResult Skader(LeBlenderValue data)
    {

        var jsonString = new WebClient { Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 }.DownloadString("myStringHere");

        var dbObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SkaderModel>>(jsonString);

        var vm = new MonitorTableViewModel(){Skader = dbObj, gridData = data};
        return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/Monitor/Skader.cshtml", vm);
    }
```

Comment: Is that error displayed in the browser? If so, is there more displayed? The actual error might be buried deep in there. If there's something more specific in there it might help. If you're debugging locally try pressing CTRL-ALT-E in Visual Studio and checking the box next to Common Language Runtime Exceptions. That will cause execution to stop whenever an exception is thrown. The first step will be to find out what the exception actually is.

Comment: Yes that really is everything my browser displays, the console is clean. if i debug my project locally i never run into that issue. I tried what you said about CTRL-ALT-E in vs, and checked the common language runtime exceptions, ran through all my pages (not a big site), no issues. - I read somewhere it could be a tick related issue, but i cannot make my method async https://stackoverflow.com/a/46148196/10249659